# Receiving MySQL Error in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

BACKGROUND: I am using PHPMyAdmin tool to run MySQL queries. MySQL version is 5.1.55. I have been using MySQL and this PHPMyAdmin tool for about 7 years and have never seen this error.  I am trying to do a simple update query changing ne to gb (column = team, table = info).  When I use PHPMyAdmin to try to make the changes,

I get the error message:

```
UPDATE `pickem`.`info` SET `team` = 'gb' WHERE CONVERT(`info`.`team` USING utf8) = \'ne\'.
```

QUESTION: What is going wrong here? What is the CONVERT Using UTF8 message coming from.  How can I get this to just update the fields I want?  I have tried to type the SQL code in myself ex: `update info set team ="gb" where team = "ne"` , but that does not work either.  I get the error message:

```
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 22
STR: =\
SQL: update info set team =\"gb\" where team = \"ne\"
```

It seems the system is putting the slashes in there and it is not letting me do this simple update query.

I appreciate any advice on how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: mysql is different than sql-server

Comment: oh, ok.  I was just clicking the tag that the site suggested.  Can you help with my question?

Comment: Is `magic_quotes_gpc` on?

Comment: use following query update info set team ='gb' where team = 'ne'

Comment: I tried artm's suggestion and it didn't work.  This is the error message I received:  There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 22
STR: =\
SQL: update info set team =\'gb\' where team = \'ne\'

Comment: @daveA I meant to turn it off if it is on.

Comment: Do you know how I can turn off the magic quotes using the myPHPAdmin tool, or is there a query I can type?

Comment: @daveA see http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: I don't have access to the php.ini file, as php / mysql is offered on yahoo's server.

Answer (score 0):

> You are using phpMyAdmin, right? Try using [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).
>
> Also check your PHP version, `gpc_magic_quotes` is already removed at PHP 5.4.0

I tried running your code on phpMyAdmin, removed the backslashes at `\'ne\'` and its running fine.

Try running a simple update query in HeidiSQL and check if the problem exists.

```
UPDATE `pickem`.`info` SET `team` = 'gb'
```

If it runs fine, modify it like

```
UPDATE `pickem`.`info` SET `team` = 'gb' WHERE `team` = 'ne'
```

Additional sidenote - check the encoding and data types. You might have overlooked something...

If your query runs fine on HeidiSQL, you can safely assume that something is wrong with your phpMyAdmin installation/configuration

EDIT:

Are the values you are providing contain '\' inside them? If so, you have to do it like

```
UPDATE `pickem`.`info` SET `team` = 'gb\\'
```

EDIT 2:

For the meantime, try to use this to solve your problem temporarily.

```
UPDATE `pickem`.`info` SET `team` = CONCAT('en') WHERE `team` = CONCAT('gb')
```

EDIT 3:

If all else fails, you probably should get [this](http://www.sequelpro.com/) or [this](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). Since you are on PHP 5.3, I am afraid to say that the `gpc_magic_quotes` option might have been enabled by your hosting provider. Contact them.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  My php version is 5.3.6, it is hosted by yahoo, well Aabaco now.  You're right, I am using PHPMyAdmin.  I went to the HeidiSQL page but I am using Mac so I'm trying to figure out how to download a version that works on Mac.  Also, I never used any slashes (\) in any of my queries.  When I see the error message, it adds them in there. In regards to the encoding types, I have the fields set to UTF8_Unicode.

Comment: Quoted from HeidiSQL download page... "HeidiSQL runs fine on Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10) and - with Wine - on any Linux and newer MacOS X versions." Give it a try. Back to the issue, did you try to execute the queries I provided in phpMyAdmin? If yes, did you encounter the same error?

Comment: I'm on the wine page but I cant figure out how to download a mac version.  Anyways, I tried to run your code, and it failed each time.  I tried it without any slashes but when the error message comes back there are slashes in the code.  Somehow they are getting added.

Comment: try a number, UPDATE `pickem`.`info` SET `team` = 1, Also try a different browser.

Comment: using a number worked fine.  I typed: update info set team =1 (I used no quotes or slashes)

Comment: This is going to sound crazy, but I added a primary key field (id) at the beginning of the table and that seemed to work.  I have no idea what difference it made, but now I can update the table no problem.  Strange.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds crazy but, having encountered issues with phpMyAdmin, all I can say is that it's strange... Good to know that you were able to fix your problem.